# Java ArrayLists in Stata

Tags: arraylist, stata

I am pretty new to Stata but have done OO coding in Java.

I am wondering if there is a way of using something similar as an ArrayList for Stata?

Answer (score 1):

There's something called `macro`s which can maybe simulate what you want. 
*local* is one of the flavors in which a `macro`comes. See below some examples
trying to "simulate" some Java methods for Array Lists found here: 
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/array_lists.html

```
clear all
set more off

* Analogous: ArrayList listTest = new ArrayList( );
local listTest
display "`listTest'"

* Analogous: listTest.add( "first_item" );
local listTest first_item
display "`listTest'"

* Analogous: listTest.add( "second_item" );
local listTest `listTest' second_item
display "`listTest'"

* Analogous: listTest.get(2)
local oneElement : word 2 of `listTest'
display "`oneElement'"

* Analogous: listTest.remove(2);
local toremove "second_item"
local newList: list listTest - toremove
display "`newList'"
```

See (at least) `help macro`, `help extended_fcn` and `help macrolists` for information
on **macros**, **extended macro functions** and **macro lists**.

Furthermore, the Stata manual **[P] class** states:

> Stata’s two programming languages, ado and Mata, each support
>   object-oriented programming. This manual entry explains
>   object-oriented programming in ado. Most users interested in
>   object-oriented programming will wish to do so in Mata. See [M-2]
>   class to learn about object-oriented programming in Mata.

and section 7.2 treats *Arrays and array elements*.

There's plenty of resources on the subject but take time to read Stata official documentation; it's very good.